# Can not start an instance using custom images on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-compute-engine, autoscaling, google-cloud-platform

I'm running my Production on GCP in an **instance group** with autoscaling on. Then, I tried to scale up my servers, but an instance couldn't start from my **everyday backup image**.

I checked the logs and I saw that my instance was inserted and automatically deleted.

[Logs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evrQe.png)

Then I tried to create an instance (not in any **instance groups**), I checked the logs, and I found that the instance was started after nearly 10 minutes.

[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT2iI.png)

I wanted to know why it took almost 10 minutes to start an instance from a custom image?

Comment: "but an instance could start " you mean "couldn't"?
Do you have any scaling policies set up? Isn't your instance terminated because of a scaling down event? Or maybe it's not reporting as healthy?

Comment: autoscaling is using templates, not custom images

Comment: @VincentTeyssier: yes, you're right. I define template's boot disk to my custom image.

Comment: @AdamOcsvari: about scaling policies, it bases on CPU usage.
Actually, I was running with 1 instance; the instance group then was scaled up. As you can see in my logs https://i.stack.imgur.com/evrQe.png, I waited for 5 minutes then the instance was inserted and terminated automatically. Of course, this instance was reported as unhealthy.

Comment: I have two guesses: The instance has a startup script which is too slow or not working and the instance is not passing the health-check (or not enough quickly). In this case the termination is because of unhealthy instance.
Or it's a scaling up, scaling down too quickly. After scaling up you have 2X more CPU usage which drops the average usage to the half. If it's under the scale down threshold it triggers a scale down after the cool-down period. (Scaling up at 60%, scaling down at 40%.) At scale down the lowest utilized instance is selected for termination.

Comment: Adding to @AdamOcsvari OP can also specify `cooldown` periods to prevent creation and deletion of VMs immediately on trigger.

Comment: @PrateekGupta, I set `cool-down period` and `initial delay` to 10 minutes and the VM successfully started.

Comment: @AdamOcsvari, here is my logs for starting a VM from my custom image:
1. http://i.imgur.com/eFcZkxu.png
2. http://i.imgur.com/UYpu6By.png
3. http://i.imgur.com/JXppDbO.png
But I don't know why it's quite slow, is it because of my custom image size?

Comment: image size: 50GB, snapshot size: 6.26GB